# does left join order effect the order of the list? SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server, left-join

I have two tables which have some common Fields which I use to join both tables in one. The Point is I need all the rows from one Table( even the rows that do not match with the other table) in the final result Table.

For this, I need to left join both tables and put the one that I completely need on the left side and it works. The problem is that I lose the Order of this table because I get every common row first and then all the other Rows what I do not really want.

How can I keep the order of my table?

I am using SQL server 2008

Comment: using `ORDER BY`

Comment: you did not loose the ordering of the table because there is no ordering. SqlServer will return your data in any order it sees fit. If you want a specific ordering you just need to add the 'order by' clause at the end of your query

Comment: My table has only one Column and its a string. when i order by this column i might get it orderd alphabetically what i do not need

Comment: then you are out of luck. Tables are unordered sets data (in SQL)

Comment: then what order do you need ? SQL Server has  no ordering it can be random. Without an 'order by' clause your data can be in different order each time you run the query

Comment: Does your table have an index? In certain setups you may find it's ordering on that (or rather it's quickest for SQL to return the data in that order). But like people have said:If you don't tell SQL server an order to return your data in then the order returned is not guaranteed. You can even get "odd" results like the order being consistent on one server and different/inconsistent on another (a situation I came across).

If you "like" the order you have now then insert that into a new table with an identity column, join to that and order on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to add an extra column to your table and make it an identity field.
Then you can you can use that field in your order by

```
create table MyTable(Name varchar(100), OrderField int identity)
```

because it is an identity field you can omit it when inserting, like this

```
insert into MyTable (Name) values ('whatever')
```

then you can do

```
select t.Name
from   MyTable t
order by t.OrderField
```

and joining on whatever

```
 select t.Name,
        mt.somefieldfromthattable
 from   MyTable t
   left outer join MyOtherTable mt on t.Name = mt.Name
 order by t.OrderField
```

Beware, if there are many records in this table than someday the OrderField will reach its maximum and start over again.
If that could be the case then use a datetime field for ordering, allthough it will be slower it will never have that problem

Answer (score 2):

No, you are not losing any ordering, because you never had any to begin with.

SQL tables are composed of *unordered sets*.  Unless you explicitly use an `ORDER BY` statement, the order of the results returned is *not* guaranteed.

If you want the results in a specific order, `ORDER BY` that column in your query.

Comment: I'd add this to your answer for them... https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/conor_cunningham_msft/2008/08/27/no-seatbelt-expecting-order-without-order-by/

Comment: @scsimon that is my favorite article about ordering. It does such a great job of explaining what happens and even provides a repeatable example.

Answer (score 2):

Without writing `ORDER BY` in a query the result is not guaranteed to be sorted in any particular order, you must have specified `ORDER BY` in order to retrieve the records in your requested order.

[MSDN BOL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188385(v=sql.105).aspx)

> The ORDER BY clause does not guarantee ordered results when these
>   constructs are queried, unless ORDER BY is also specified in the query
>   itself

.

Comment: I upload data from an Excel table that has a specific Order and i need the result to be exactly in the same Order like my Table. this is all!!

Comment: a table has no order. That is also all

Comment: Then apply a unique row number to your excel for the order you want it in, then order by this column @memo_star since you don't want it alphabetically

Comment: Can you post some sample data to have a look.

Comment: @memo_star then add an autonumeric column to your table

Answer (score 1):

Use an `ORDER BY` column. This will order the tables according to how you want it.

The default is ascending which means that it will be ordered from A - Z or the smallest to largest number. You can specify `DESC` at the end of the command which will order Z - A or from the largest to smallest integer

It looks like this...

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName FROM Person ORDER BY FirstName ASC/DESC
```

See [ORDER BY at W3 Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp)

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to add an `IDENTITY` column to act as natural order by insertion. Then use the `ORDER BY` on the identity column. Any data you enter into that table will be ordered by the time in which it was inserted.